# How to merge same hashes in array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have:

```
array = [{:external_product_id=>"A", :quantity=>1}, {:external_product_id=>"A", :quantity=>2}, {:external_product_id=>"B", :quantity=>1}]
```

and want to transform it into:

```
array = [{:external_product_id=>"A", :quantity=>3}, {:external_product_id=>"B", :quantity=>1}]
```

i.e., merging products with the same id (`"A"`) together. Is there any easier way to do this than using `map`, `select`, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anything like this?

```
array.group_by { |item| item[:external_product_id] }
     .map do |external_product_id, items| 
       { 
         external_product_id: external_product_id, 
         quantity: items.sum { |item| item[:quantity] }
       } 
     end

=> [{:external_product_id=>"A", :quantity=>3}, {:external_product_id=>"B", :quantity=>1}]
```